# Question about open subsets in topology

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble understanding the following theorem.
Any open ball B(x;r) in a metric space X is an open subset of X.

I understand that intuitively it contains all the points in the open ball except the boundary points. But for this ball to be an open subset, every point of B(x;r) must be an interior point of B(x;r) right?
But for a point to be an interior point,  there needs to be a ball with the point being the center. The question is that there is always a tiny bit of a distance between this center and the boundary of B(x;r) and within this distance(gap), there exist points of B(x;r) which also have to work as a center point right? Doesn't that mean that not all points of B(x;r) are interior points?

To put it another way, pick a point that is extremely close to the bounday of B(x;r). Can you make an open ball inside this B(x;r) with that point being the center no matter how close the point is to the boundary?

Comment: Hint: take the diameter of the "inside" ball to be $r/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, logically (rather than empirically) it should be ensured. To see this, let $\delta \geq 0$; let $r - \delta \leq |y-x| < r$. Then you can make $y$ as close to the imaginary boundary of $B(x;r)$ as desired by making $\delta$ sufficiently close to $r$. Now can we form an open ball $B(y; r')$ of center $y$ and radius $r' > 0$? Yes of course; for example, taking $r' :=r - (\delta/2)$ suffices.

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then for all $x \in X$ and $\epsilon >0$, the set $B(x,\epsilon)$ is open.

To see why this is true, suppose that $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$. Then we have that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. Thus set $r=\epsilon - d(x,y)>0$. If $z \ in B(y,r)$, then $d(z,y) < r$.

From the triangle inequality, we then have that $d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) < d(x,y) + r = d(x,y) + \epsilon - d(x,y) = \epsilon$. Thus $ z \in B(x,\epsilon)$ and $B(y,r)$ is contained in $B(x,\epsilon)$.

So no matter how close a point $y \in B(x, \epsilon)$ is to the boundary (ie how close $d(x,y)$ is to $\epsilon$) we can always find a really small positive value for $r$ such that $B(y,r)$ is contained in $B(x,\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong as written (because in trivial [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) where only open sets are empty one and whole space, not surprisingly, not all balls are open) and trivial in corrected version (every metric space  $X$ posess metric topology, where you explicitly state the open subsets are arbitrary unions of finite intersections of *open balls* $B(x_0, R) : x \in X, d(x_0, x) < R$). So, if you translate whatever strange definitions you have to standard ones, it's not a theorem but tautologically true or false statement.

Comment: finite intersections are not needed. The open balls satisfy the requirements for being a base for a topology. So unions suffice to generate the topology.